# Using LOOKUP Functions with <= and >=

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Display of Excel Sheet]

I attempting to use the LOOKUP functions in Excel in a nested(?) fashion and with ranges of data. In the attached picture, the left-hand table is my data that extends for another 360 rows or so. Each row has a unique ID (I've taken this data from a larger set so I wanted to retain it), a State postal abbreviation, and the income level for that data point (each row is data from a different zipcode).

The table on the right is the metadata - quintile levels for income in each state. For each row on the left, I want to look up the state abbreviation from the metadata, then use the adjacent income level to determine and print out the appropriate quintile based on that row in the metadata. I anticipate that the solution would use some form of the lookup functions and inequalities, but I'll take any solution.

Comment: Can you mock up an expected result so we know what to aim for? It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to show that next highest quintile number? Or the text "Third quintile"??

Comment: My mistake. I realized some same output would've helped.https://imgur.com/a/AthHolA  That shows the sample output i was looking for. For example, the median income in row 1 is 31975 from AZ. Because that its between 36358 (second quintile) and 14167 (lowest quintile) in the row for AZ in the left table, it prints "Second Quintile" in D2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this approach you need Office 365, with the new XMatch function, which can do an approximate match for next bigger number without requiring the data to be sorted.

The formula is

```
=INDEX($J$1:$N$1,XMATCH(C2,INDEX(J:J,MATCH(B2,H:H,0),0):INDEX(N:N,MATCH(B2,H:H,0)),1))
```

[image]

If you don't have XMatch, you would need to re-arrange the lookup columns from Highest to Lowest. Then you can use

```
=INDEX($J$1:$N$1,MATCH(C2,INDEX(J:J,MATCH(B2,H:H,0),0):INDEX(N:N,MATCH(B2,H:H,0)),-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you paste this formula on cell D4, would the result be your expected output?

```
(Highest Quintile for California)
=INDEX(N:N,MATCH(B4,B:B,0))
```

Paste this to D5

```
(Lowest Quintile for Ohio)
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(B5,B:B,0))
```

The last 0 (zero) in the formula is the match type. It can be replaced with:

- 1 - less than
- 0 - exact match
- -1 - greater than

depending on your need. Did I get your point?

Comment: My mistake. I realized some same output would've helped.https://imgur.com/a/AthHolA  That shows the sample output i was looking for. For example, the median income in row 1 is 31975 from AZ. Because that its between 36358 (second quintile) and 14167 (lowest quintile) in the row for AZ in the left table, it prints "Second Quintile" in D2.

Answer (score 0):

Your information is a bit sparse. So I tell you what I did and you take it from there.

First I created a named range to comprise 2 columns of your median income table, state and income. Then I created this formula to extract the income by state.

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,Income,2,FALSE)
```

Observe that the state name is in column B and the income in the 2nd column of the *Income* range. Your list may be structured differently. The key to it is that the *Income* range must have the State in its first column and the 2 in the formula just counts columns from State to Income.

If you place this formula on the same sheet as the *Income* range it will just produce a copy of the *Income* column. But that isn't what I did. I placed it in a blank column on the *Quintile* tab. That happened to be column J, since A:G is taken up with your data, notably, C:G with the columns for quintile numbers. Observe in this transfer that column B displays the state abbreviations. By coincidence it's column B in both sheets. The relevant column is the one on the *Quintile* sheet. So, the formula still shows the median income for each state but the sequence is determined by the sequence of state names on the tab where the formula resides, and that is the requirement here.

Next, I created this formula and placed it in column K of the *Quintile* sheet.

```
=MATCH(J2,C2:G2,1)
```

This formula determines the column in C:G where the value in J2 is matched. J2, of course, contains the Median income drawn by the VLOOKUP. If that number is nothing it will be interpreted as zero and the lowest quintile returned. Read up on the precise method of the MATCH function.

Now J2 can be integrated into the formula. I did that in a copy of the MATCH formula in column L.

```
[L2] =MATCH(VLOOKUP($B2,Income,2,FALSE),C2:G2,1)
```

Observe that the formula in K and L have the same result. I copied them down a few rows to make sure. I got a lot of #N/A errors in this exercise resulting from state abbreviations in the *Quintile* sheet not being found in the *Income* range. I think that information is useful. Therefore I didn't suppress it.

The result so far is the quintile, numbered from 1 to 5. I wanted to make sure that the numbers are correct. Therefore I "translated" them to the number in the *Quintile* table.

For this purpose I created another named range, called this one "Quintiles", comprising of columns C:G. It's important that this range should start in row 1. The columns could be any other columns (not C:G) but they must be the same as specified in the formula, with the lowest quintile being the first. And this became my formula in column M.

```
[M2] =INDEX(Quintiles,ROW(),L2)
```

If you actually need this number you can replace the reference to L2 in the formula with the formula in L2.